# Generalizing "sequence" for all functors?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I have this code:

```
fmapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (t, a) -> m (t, b)
fmapM f (id, e) = do 
  ev <- f e
  return (id, ev)
```

which basically applies the function to the 2nd element in the tuple and then "extracts" the monad.
Since the tuple is a functor, is there a way to generalize this for all functors? I cannot think of an implementation, but the type signature should be:

```
fmapM :: (Monad m, Functor f) => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m f b
```

it would seem like the 2nd step would be a "sequence" operation, which extracts the monad from another functor (the list). But sequence is not generalized to all functors. Can you come up with a generic implementation of fmapM?

*Edit*: I've realized that an old version of hugs did have this function implemented. However, I can't find the code. Now, it is suggested that I use foldable/traversable to achieve the same.

Comment: Ah, I see the `fmapM` you mean in old Hugs, but that was just a less general version of `Traversable`. It's still a class with a different implementation for each type.

Comment: (You can derive `fmap` -- as well as a lot of other functions -- from just `traverse`, but not vice versa.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `traverse`, from `Data.Traversable`:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Note that you can't `traverse` any `Functor` -- for example, `(r ->)` -- so there's a separate subclass of `Traversable` functors. Also note that you don't need `Monad` -- just `Applicative` (this generalization is useful).

Comment: A minimal implementation of Traversable for `(,) a` would be something like `sequenceA (a, b) = do { b' <- b; return $ (,) a b' }` in monadic notation and `(,) a <$> b` in applicative notation... but traversable wants `(,) a` to be Foldable as well, and that does not seem to be possible...

Comment: It is possible. In fact, if you defined `traverse` (rather than `sequenceA`), you can automatically write both a `Functor` and a `Foldable` instance using `fmapDefault` and `foldMapDefault` respectively.

Comment: `traverse` for `(,) a` looks like: `traverse f (x,y) = (,) x <$> f y`. `foldMap` and `fmap` look like: `foldMap f (x,y) = f y`; `fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)`. `traverse` is a direct generalization of the two.

Comment: thanks. any reason why `(,) a` has a functor instance in the prelude, but there's no foldable and traversable instances? Given the functor instance in the prelude, there's little else that the foldable and traversable instances can do that makes sense, other than act on the second element and repack everything together...

Comment: Nope. [No reason](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/commit/a9a9ce679e0c57437a17824cd6366d085248d217).